# COPY if column exists

Tags: postgresql, copy, plpgsql

I am writing a PLPGSQL function, that needs to import files into a table.

I have created a temporary table with 4 columns

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_ID_Customer (
        ID int4 NULL,
        Name varchar(2000) NULL,
        CodeEx varchar(256) NULL, 
        AccountID varchar(256) NULL
    )ON COMMIT DROP;
```

I am then trying to copy a file into this table, with the following

```
EXECUTE format('COPY tmp_ID_Customer FROM %L (FORMAT CSV, HEADER TRUE, DELIMITER(''|''))', _fileName);
```

The issue I have is some of these files only contain the first 3 columns.

So I am receiving an error saying

```
 extra data after last expected column
```

I've tried specifying the columns, but as the final column doesn't always exist. I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the columns you are copying:

```
COPY tmp_ID_Customer(id, name, codex) FROM ...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. When I specify columns I get an error saying  extra data after last expected column. On files that contain all 4 columns. Files with 3 columns work fine

Comment: Right. You will have to use a different command, depending on how many columns are in the file.